# Android ViewPager with ImageViews

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager that houses 4 frame layouts each with a different image as its background. I have tried several ways of loading and resizing the images but the viewpager is still laggy when you swipe; since it has to change the background images accordingly.

Other apps such as QuizUp and most of Google's own apps have images on the tutorial but and they're very smooth. Is there any way to achieve the same effect; keep the images as backgrounds while optimizing the viewpager's performance?

Here is my viewpager adapter;

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TextView text1 = null, text2 = null, text3 = null, text4 = null;
        ImageView background;
        Button begin;

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lifestyle, container, false);
                text1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text3);
                text2 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text4);
                text3 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text5);
                background = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.background);

                background.setImageResource(R.drawable.tlifestyle);
                break;
            case 1:
                layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sports, container, false);
                text1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text3);
                text2 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text4);
                text3 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text5);
                background = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.background);

                background.setImageResource(R.drawable.tsports);
                break;
            case 2:
                layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.events, container, false);
                text1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                text2 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                text3 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text3);
                text4 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text4);
                background = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.background);

                background.setImageResource(R.drawable.tevents);
                break;
            case 3:
                layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.intro_to_categories, container, false);
                text1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.welcomeText);
                text2 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.findText);
                text3 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dont_stress);
                text4 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dont_stress_2);
                begin = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.begin);

                Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mpashofont.otf");
                begin.setTypeface(typeface);

                begin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(AppTutorial.this, AppSetup.class));
                    }
                });
                break;
        }

        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mpashofont.otf");
        assert text1 != null && text2 != null && text3 != null;
        text1.setTypeface(typeface);
        text2.setTypeface(typeface);
        text3.setTypeface(typeface);
        if (text4 != null) {
            text4.setTypeface(typeface);
        }

        container.addView(layout);

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((FrameLayout) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the solution you have so far?

Comment: put image on main layout.

Comment: I have tried using BitmapFactory.Options to try and resize the images, i have tried using fragments as the viewpager items and setting the images as backgrounds, i am currently using frame layouts as the viewpager items since i thought they would be lighter but i still have the same problem. If i remove the image backgrounds, the viewpager is smooth.

Comment: can you paste your adapter?

Comment: @AmarbirSingh i tried putting it on the main layout but it was slower since it has to switch between 3 different images

Comment: @SanketKachhela see updated question for viewpager adapter code

Comment: @AlexKombo you are just using begin(Button) so remove all id's from the layout which you declared except begin button from the last one. No need of the declaration of text view if they are static. Try This

Comment: @AmarbirSingh if i remove the ids i get a null pointer exception when i set the typeface

Comment: Did you set offscreen page limit? If you set it to 0, than viewpager should create view when you start sliding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess as per your code of adapter 
 i can see that you have 3 textview and 1 background image for all different inflated layouts.

and you are creating typeface on each swipe so place this typeface initialization code in your constructor

and it is better to change data as per position.

like this

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    TextView text1 = null, text2 = null, text3 = null, text4 = null;
    ImageView background;

    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    text1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text3);
    text2 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text4);
    text3 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text5);
    background = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.background);

   text1.setText(arr[position]);
   ...
}
```

Comment: your method works, and a big change in improvement in performance is evident. Thanks a lot for that. 

But i think now my problem lies in the different images i'm using for backgrounds (full screen). The largest one is around 130kb. Could it be they are too heavy and if so, how can i load them while maximizing performance?

Comment: try to load images with universal image loader. you can load images from url, drawable and Url.. btw thanks for accepting answer :)